# .NET Standard Project File Format for Analyzers

Tags: visual-studio, format, project, roslyn

I don't have access to NuGet currently, and I need to add a Roslyn analyzer (StyleCop) to a new .NET Standard class library project.  What manual file edits (project.csproj, package.config) do I need to make?  I already have the StyleCop nuget package downloaded from installing it in a .NET Framework class library earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked at an existing .NET Standard class library project with StyleCop installed.  Here's the relevant portions of the project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>

  ...

  <ItemGroup>
    <AdditionalFiles Include="stylecop.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.1.118">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  ...

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the StyleCop package in your NuGet cache, what you posted in your answer will work and it will work if you clear your cache when have access to NuGet.org.

But if you have an analyzer library that is not on a NuGet package that you want to use, you can explicitly add analyzers:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Analyzer Include="<path to analyzer dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```